# php and xdebug module in docker

Tags: php, docker

i wanna make a sample dockerized php application with xdebug module and my problem is when i open `http://127.0.0.1:8080` i get error `This site can’t be reached` . how can i fix this and what is best practice for this?
this is my structure of my tiny project:

- /docker

  - nginx

    - default.conf
  - php

    - conf.d

      - error_reporting.ini
      - xdebug.ini
- docker-compose.yml
- index.php

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

RUN pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:

  webserver:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./:/var/www

  php:

    build: ./docker/php/
    expose:
      - 9000
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
      - ./docker/php/conf.d/error_reporting.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/error_reporting.ini
```

default.conf :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

error_reporting.ini:

```
error_reporting=E_ALL
```

xdebug.ini:

```
zend_extension=xdebug

[xdebug]
xdebug.mode=develop,debug
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
```

Comment: I get that too.  I found that **localhost** works, so I am using that

Comment: @RohitGupta are you sure? me neither

Comment: What do you get when you type in localhost in the browser

Comment: You're mapping nginx container's port 80 to 8080 on the host. Try http://127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: @MostafaBahri you tried that? same error

Answer (score 0):

You're container name is incorrect in nginx config:

```
fastcgi_pass app:9000;
```

This should be

```
fastcgi_pass php:9000;
```

because you've named the container `php` in your compose file.